# Is there good way to guess color codes by users

Tags: javascript, jquery

I built Input via HTML , this input can guess color codes by users , I built code by jquery for guess color codes but I don't know if that was the best way or there another best way.

*Code*

```
try {
        //Check Hex
        if ($(mainInputBox).val().includes("#") && !$(mainInputBox).val().includes(",")) {
            if ($(mainInputBox).val().length === 2 || $(mainInputBox).val().length === 3 || $(mainInputBox).val().length === 4 || $(mainInputBox).val().length === 7) {
                return null;
            }
        } else if (!$(mainInputBox).val().includes("#") && !$(mainInputBox).val().includes(",")) {
            if ($(mainInputBox).val().length === 1 || $(mainInputBox).val().length === 2 || $(mainInputBox).val().length === 3 || $(mainInputBox).val().length === 6) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        //Check Rgb
        if ($(mainInputBox).val().includes("rgb(") && $(mainInputBox).val().includes(")") && $(mainInputBox).val().match(new RegExp(",", "g")).length === 2) {
            return null;
        } else if (!$(mainInputBox).val().includes("rgb(") && !$(mainInputBox).val().includes(")") && $(mainInputBox).val().match(new RegExp(",", "g")).length === 2) {
            return null;
        }
        // Check Hsl
        if ($(mainInputBox).val().includes("hsl(") && $(mainInputBox).val().includes(")") && $(mainInputBox).val().match(new RegExp(",", "g")).length === 2 && $(mainInputBox).val().includes("%")) {
            return null;
        } else if (!$(mainInputBox).val().includes("hsl(") && !$(mainInputBox).val().includes(")") && $(mainInputBox).val().match(new RegExp(",", "g")).length === 2 && $(mainInputBox).val().includes("%")) {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Something went wrong. Please Check Color")
    }
```

Is that best way or there another way to guess color codes by users

Comment: Is the user or jquery guessing?

Comment: Looks like a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does this code work? Are you asking for a code review? There is a different site you can ask on for that (stack exchange code review)...check if your question might be more suitable there.

Comment: @NickLeBlanc What is the stackexchange website ?

Comment: Quoting an answer of Meta: "Peer review of your code is an important activity for most programmers. Once you have working code, it is an important part of your professional development to have others look over your code to find hidden mistakes, or just to improve your overall code quality and style. If your having trouble with a piece of code, your question likely belongs on Stack Overflow. But if you have working code that you simply would like to review with others, your question belongs on Code Review SE."

Comment: @ADyson It works but I fear there will be a better way

Comment: "Is there a better way" questions are code review questions.